# What's the difference between void* and void**?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

**It's the special property that void* can also be assigned a pointer to a pointer and cast back and the original value is received.**

I read this line somewhere. Does it means `void*` and `void**` are same?
What is the difference?

**Edit**

`void*` can hold any pointer. Then what's `void**` needed for?

Comment: You need void** when you need to dereference it and find out what the void* it's pointing to is, or even change that void* to something else. You can't dereference void*, or shouldn't without heavy-duty safety goggles on.

Comment: Well, if you want to think about it that way, what are any pointer types other than `void*` needed for?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

One points at a black hole.

The other points at the thing pointing at the black hole.

---

They're not really the same thing, but pointers can be converted to `void *`. You can convert `int *` to a `void *` because, well, it's a pointer. `void **` is *still* a pointer (it just points to a pointer), and since it's a pointer, you can convert it to a `void *`. That make any sense?

That said, I don't think I've ever had a use for a `void **`, but if you needed an array of `void *`s, then the type would be `void **`. (In C) `void *` is often used to hold a pointer to some user data - but you won't know ahead of time what type that data will be. If you had an array of those, then `void **`.

Since you also have this tagged as C++: The previous case doesn't really apply: you could use a `std::vector<void *>`. Really, `void *` might be questionable - an abstract base might fit your purposes better. `void *` is useful mostly in C.

Comment: I've used void ** as a parameter to a function that called a function pointer passed to it. In this particular case, the baton was mutable.

Comment: An array of `void*`s is actually `void*[n]`.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Strictly speaking, yes. When I wrote the post, I was thinking more along the lines of a dynamically allocated array, or an array who's size is not known.

Answer (score 7):

A void** is a pointer to a void*.  A void* can be converted back and forth to any pointer type (including void**).  So you can do:

```
char* -> void*
void* -> void**
void** -> void*
void* -> char*
```

You can *not* do:

```
char* -> void**
void** -> char*
```

so they are not the same.

Comment: Why we can't do the conversions from and to `void**` though?

Answer (score 3):

A `void *` can hold any pointer. Since there are no actual `void` objects, a `void *` is always a pointer to some other type.

A `void **` is a pointer to a pointer to void, or the address of a `void *`, i.e., the address of a pointer to void. This is an actual type and doesn't have any magic properties.

But since a `void *` can hold any pointer, it can also hold, for example, a `void **`.

```
void **f(int x) {
   static void *y;
   static int *iy;
   y = &x;
   iy = &x;
   // return &iy; // not ok
   return &y; // ok
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the opposite, a void** can hold a void*, is NOT guaranteed.

Comment: Good point, I was trying to say that, actually. That's why that one return line, which attempts to put a `void *` into a `void **`, is commented out with the *not ok* note.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to store some pointer or anything you will probably use void*.

However if you want to write a function which can be able to initialize this magic pointer, then you need pass this argument to this function as void**

```
void   fun1();
int    fun2(int);
double fun3(long);
bool   fun4(int, long, double);


int rand(void** pp)
{
  switch(time()%4)
  {
    case 0: *pp = fun1; return 0;
    case 1: *pp = fun2; return 1;
    case 2: *pp = fun3; return 2;
    case 3: *pp = fun4; return 3;
  }
}

int main()
{
    void* pointer;
    int funId;

    funId = rand(&pointer);

    setCallback(pointer, funId);
}
```

Comment: Right idea, but you're confusing function pointers with data pointers--this is non-standard.  Make that four different struct types instead and you're right on.

Answer (score 1):

One major difference is that the rule you quote in bold does not apply to void**.

Answer (score 0):

void* is a pointer (or a pointer to the beginning of a unknown type array).
void* is a pointer to the address of a pointer (or a pointer to the beginning of a 2D array).

Also, if you are writing in C (and not in C++), then there is no by-reference parameter, only by value or by pointer.

E.g.

```
// By value C and C++
void MyFunction(int a)
{
}

// By pointer C and C++
void MyFunction(int* a)
{
}

// By reference C++ only
void MyFunction(int& a)
{
}
```

If you want a function that modifies the address of a pointer (e.g. void* ptr;)
and enables the calling code to by affected by the change,
then you need to pass a pointer by reference pass ptr to (void*&) and use ptr inside the function
or pass a pointer to a pointer (void**) and pass &ptr and use *ptr inside the function.